# Encontrar una lista anidada mediante un objeto de esta

Tags: python, lista

Tengo que encontrar e imprimir la lista anidada mediante un valor insertado (exactamente el segundo valor). Funciona con la primera lista, pero cuando inserto las demás regresa a pedirme un nuevo valor.

```
tabla = [[1, 11, 17, 13, 9], [2, 22, 22, 14, 20], [3, 33, 20, 14, 13], [4, 44, 24, 14, 20], [5, 55, 19, 10, 14]]
```

Código

```
def buscar():
placa = int(input("Inserte el numero de placa: "))
for i in tabla:
    if i[1] == placa:
        print(i)
```

Resultado

Inserte el numero de placa: 11

[1, 11, 17, 13, 9]

Inserte el numero de placa: 22

Inserte el numero de placa:

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Algo no debes estar haciendo bien al ejecutar la prueba, porque tu código funciona tal cual: [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3v81.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3v81.png)